# my core data is store only one number to one attribute not saving a multiple attributes swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

i have an app to calculate the number of pressing the button,and i have a data base (coreData) and i have an attribute num1 and attribute num2 , when I run the app the core data will save in attribute num1 only or num2 only and give me the another number = 0

note: i have a variable i because when i = 0  i want core data to save into num1 attribute , and if i = 1 i want the core data to save into num2 attribute

my save method like this :

```
func save()
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    //Data is in this case the name of the entity
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Mm",inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let options = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)


    if (i == 0)
    {
      options.setValue(u, forKey: "num1")   
    }

    else if (i == 1)
    {
        options.setValue(u, forKey: "num2")    
    }
   do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch
    {
        print("error")
    }


}
```

and my read method is :

```
func read()
{
    do
    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mm")

        let fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        var  j = fetchedResults.count-1

            let single_result = fetchedResults[j]
            let out = single_result.valueForKey("num1") as! NSNumber
            print("num1",out)
            let out1 = single_result.valueForKey("num2") as! NSNumber
            print("num2",out1)     
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error")
    }   
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `save` function creates a new record each time it runs, and sets only `num1` or `num2`.  When you fetch the results you are just showing the last record returned, which will only have a value for `num1` or `num2`, depending on which you set when you created it

Comment: well, how can i save the both values in the same record and how can i fetch to the same values ?? @Paulw11

Comment: The first time you create a new record.  After that you update the same record and save it again.  You would use logic something like: have a property which is your NSManagedObject.  When your app starts, fetch the existing object.  If an object can't be found, then create a new object and save it.  Then when your button is pressed, update the relevant count on the object and save it again.  Do not create a new object each time